# How do I extend a class prototype with TypeScript type checking?

Tags: typescript

I have been working on a wrapper for Firebase's Firestore. Currently I have written a `Collection` type which is for a large part a proxy to Firestore's `Query` class. Which means it forwards most methods to the underlying Query, but then it wraps whatever the query returns into another `Collection`. This allows me to chain query methods together while still retaining the `Collection` type. It allows me to write code like this:

```js
class Post {
  static collection = "posts"

  public title: string
  public body: string
  public created: Date

  constructor(title: string, body: string, created: Date) {
    this.title = title
    this.body = body
    this.created = created
  }
}

// collection(Post) just returns a Collection<Post>,
// and after the where method it's still a Collection<Post>
let posts = collection(Post).where("created", "<", new Date)
```

And I've been able to write the type definition of `Collection<Model>` such that TypeScript understands that it contains all the methods from `Query`, but that the return types of those methods will always be `Collection<Model>`. So that works very nicely for code completion. To explain why all of this is beneficial for me would take a bit too long to explain and it's irrelevant for my question.

My question is, I would actually like to be able to do this very differently. I would like to make `Post` itself work as a proxy to `Query`, just like `Collection` does now. Except the main difference is that then I don't want to use the query methods as normal methods, but instead as  static methods. So I could write code like this:

```js
let posts = Post.where("created", "<", new Date)

// but this should also still work:
let post = new Post("title", "body", new Date)
```

Like I think I know how to write this in Javascript. Something along the lines of:

```js
class PostShadow {
  constructor(title, body, created) {
    this.title = title
    this.body = body
    this.created = created
  }
}

const Post = new Proxy(PostShadow, {
  /* write my query-forwarding-code here */ 
})
```

But I don't want to have to write a `PostShadow` class. I want to just be able to write `class Post extends Model {}` or better yet `@Model class Post {}`, but in a way that TypeScript understands the type definition of `Post`. And so far I haven't found out how to make TypeScript understand that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)?  Or barring that, a link to some web IDE that already has this working?  It would be very helpful for me to be able to experiment and test any suggestion I have instead of just suggesting something that might or might not work.  Good luck!

Comment: Hey @jcalz, thanks for replying.  Are you the same guy from reddit? I tried pasting the typescript playground link here, but the link is too long. So I pasted it in [the reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/imdds1/how_do_i_extend_a_class_prototype_with_typescript/g47zvo8?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) instead.